# adding some user's properties in spring security UI Grails plugin

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

In Grails plugin **spring-security-ui:1.0-RC2** i need to add some properties to the registering user such as first name,last name and mobile number , where i could add these properties.

Thanks

Answer (score -2):

Look in your **domain** folder, here you can find **User** domain, add fields to it.

Documentation : http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-ui/guide/single.html

But better use the latest version of plugin : spring-security plugin - http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core

Comment: Ya i have User domain related to spring security core plugin in my domains , but when i add the properties nothing shown in the registration page

Comment: He asked about  spring-security-ui, not spring-security-core. This does not answer the question regarding registration and  spring-security-ui.

Answer (score -2):

Plugins > spring-security-ui 1.0-RC2 > views > user > create.gsp and edit.gsp

Both those views need to be modified to reflect your update domain. I've had to do it manually in the past.. if there's a way to generate that would be cool, let us know if you find a way.

Comment: He's asking about registration. It's a totally different flow, and these suggestions will not affect the registration flow.